# Building URL For ListView With Picasso In Android App

Tags: java, android, json

Goal is to display images from The Movie Database with Picasso.

I am accessing json from The Movie Database.
This is the link which works,

This is the json from all popular movies

http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=e2a8069c1e18c3b7545db574817b218e

This is the url for one movie interstellar
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg

I think I need something like,

```
url http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/
getPoster_path()
```

I am pretty sure that I am building the url incorrectly. I would really really appreciate if someone could look at the url and see if I am handling it correctly.

handling json that is returned like this,

in Movie class

```
 public String getPoster_path ()
    {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path (String poster_path)
    {
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
    }
```

I am building this link like this,

Interface api (after base url is called with api key),

```
public interface api {

     @GET("/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=e2a8069c1e18c3b7545db574817b218e")
    public void getData(Callback<List<Movie>> response);

}
```

adapter class (where picasso is handled),

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    String url="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";
    private Context context;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    public adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Movie> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.movieList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv.setText(movie.getTitle());
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url+movie.getPoster_path()).resize(100,100).into(img);
        return view;
    }
}
```

In my main (where base url is called),

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<Movie> movieList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org").build();

        api movieapi = restadapter.create(api.class);

        movieapi.getData(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Movie> movies, Response response) {
                movieList = movies;
                adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,movieList);
                //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My logcat,

```
   11-06 16:55:01.332 3269-3269/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
11-06 16:55:01.333 3269-3269/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-06 16:55:01.342 3269-3269/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-06 16:55:01.345 3269-3269/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-06 16:55:01.356 3269-3269/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-06 16:55:01.356 3269-3269/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-06 16:55:01.357 3269-3269/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-06 16:55:01.365 3269-3269/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-06 16:55:01.367 1280-1420/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.wuno.moviesapp appid=10061 user=0: from pid 3269
11-06 16:55:01.367 1280-1420/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3224:com.wuno.moviesapp/u0a61 (adj 0): stop com.wuno.moviesapp
11-06 16:55:01.370 1280-1291/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 2
11-06 16:55:01.370 1280-1291/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{7c3f7b2 u0 com.wuno.moviesapp/com.wuno.moviesapp.MainActivity}
11-06 16:55:01.388 1280-1420/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{ab5c277 u0 com.wuno.moviesapp/.MainActivity t42}: app died, no saved state
11-06 16:55:01.397 1280-1734/? W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{3ab6e1a 0:com.wuno.moviesapp/u0a61}, curProc for 3224: null
11-06 16:55:01.400 3269-3269/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-06 16:55:01.454 1942-1961/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-06 16:55:01.454 1942-1961/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaeef8e80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-06 16:55:01.468 1280-1420/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 3224 uid 10061
11-06 16:55:01.906 3279-3279/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
11-06 16:55:01.907 3279-3279/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-06 16:55:01.912 3283-3283/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
11-06 16:55:01.913 3283-3283/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
11-06 16:55:01.927 3279-3279/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-06 16:55:01.932 3283-3283/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-06 16:55:01.934 3279-3279/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-06 16:55:01.943 3283-3283/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
11-06 16:55:01.954 3279-3279/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-06 16:55:01.954 3279-3279/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-06 16:55:01.955 3279-3279/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-06 16:55:01.967 3283-3283/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-06 16:55:01.967 3283-3283/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-06 16:55:01.968 3283-3283/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
11-06 16:55:01.977 3279-3279/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
11-06 16:55:01.979 3279-3279/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-06 16:55:01.989 3279-3296/? E/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
11-06 16:55:01.989 3279-3296/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
11-06 16:55:01.991 3283-3283/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-06 16:55:01.995 1280-1415/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.wuno.moviesapp/.MainActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
11-06 16:55:02.011 3283-3283/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-06 16:55:02.020 1942-1961/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
11-06 16:55:02.020 1942-1961/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
11-06 16:55:02.046 3299-3299/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-06 16:55:02.046 3299-3299/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
11-06 16:55:02.051 3299-3299/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-06 16:55:02.069 1280-1829/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 3299:com.wuno.moviesapp/u0a61 for activity com.wuno.moviesapp/.MainActivity
11-06 16:55:02.077 3299-3299/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.wuno.moviesapp-2/lib/x86
11-06 16:55:02.127 941-996/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-06 16:55:02.127 3299-3314/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-06 16:55:02.129 3299-3299/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabea8fd0, tid 3299
11-06 16:55:02.164 1942-1961/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa3651640
11-06 16:55:02.181 3299-3314/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fbc8a0, tid 3314
11-06 16:55:02.187 3299-3314/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-06 16:55:02.197 3299-3314/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-06 16:55:02.197 3299-3314/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabebf120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-06 16:55:02.228 1280-1299/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.wuno.moviesapp/.MainActivity: +186ms
11-06 16:55:02.367 3299-3314/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-06 16:55:02.367 3299-3314/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabebf300, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-06 16:55:04.341 3299-3314/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabdecce0
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you code seems to be correct but the endpoint to load your image is incorrect.

in the JSON data in the link you posted poster_path is something like this:

```
/jjBgi2r5cRt36xF6iNUEhzscEcb.jpg
```

so your complete image url will be like:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/jjBgi2r5cRt36xF6iNUEhzscEcb.jpg
```

and that is ***incorrect***, it should be

```
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/jjBgi2r5cRt36xF6iNUEhzscEcb.jpg
```

where:
`"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/" ==> is the host`
`"w500" ==> is the image width`
`"/jjBgi2r5cRt36xF6iNUEhzscEcb.jpg" ==> is the image path`

So your adaper class should be like this:

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

String url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
int size = 500; // change this to whatever works for you
private Context context;
private List<Movie> movieList;
public adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Movie> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.movieList = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
    Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    tv.setText(movie.getTitle());
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url+size+movie.getPoster_path()).resize(100,100).into(img);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I have edited this questions a few times and changed the url paths in each class. Would you please verify that your answer reflects my current url paths? When I changed my adapter class to your answer it still does not run.

Comment: I have been debugging this all day and I agree completely it was the url Typing the path in to get the json works with api key so i have the base without api query and key in main, then in api I have the after base which is query plus api key then the url for image and getPath_poster() but still getting error. I am thinking it must be something else now in the logcat.

Comment: Does this make sense to you? 11-06 17:17:23.315 1746-1746/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
11-06 17:17:23.315 1746-1746/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-06 17:17:23.322 3556-3572/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fdcf10, tid 3572